# Online neural network validator

Tags: neural-network

Does anyone know of any online resource that will allow me to plug in a neural network with provided input examples, initial weights, number of input nodes, hidden layer nodes, output nodes, expected output etc. And this resource will show the new generated weights. I want to be able to check my answers for my own neural network.

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking out something Andrej Karpathy's [ConvnetJS](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/demo/mnist.html). You can change the network parameters on the spot and see the results.

For example, here are two screenshots with the default 5x5 filters on the first layer and then changing the parameter to a 10x10 filter on the first layer:

**First Layer set to 5x5x8**
[image]

**First Layer set to 10x10x8**
[image]